# How can I put a string inside a javascript variable and "echo" variables in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am looping a json object inside javascript and I want to display values inside the looped string and later put it in my js file.

In php we can do this:

```
$var = 'This is a '.$variable.'';

echo $var;
```

Now I looked up how to do this in javascript and found it needs to be done like this:

```
var varname = 'this is a' + variable + ', and this is some more text';
```

So I tried to apply this to my loop:

```
$.each( bedrijven, function( key, value ) {
    // console.log( key + ": " + value.plaats );
    var bedrijvenlijst = "{
        title : '"+ value.title +"',
        image : 'bbvdw.jpg',
        address : '"+ value.straat value.plaats +"',
        position : {
            lat : 51.863010, // 51.8424513,
            lng : 4.235398 // 4.3307054
        },
        markerIcon : 'marker-green.png'
    },";
});
console.log(bedrijvenlijst);
```

This:

```
{
    title : '"+ value.title +"',
    image : 'bbvdw.jpg',
    address : '"+ value.straat value.plaats +"',
    position : {
        lat : 51.863010, // 51.8424513,
        lng : 4.235398 // 4.3307054
    },
    markerIcon : 'marker-green.png'
},
```

Is what I want to loop, and put the values in the looped string.

But I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

What am I doing wrong?

This is the object that I am looping if it helps:

```
var bedrijven = {"id":"10","title":"P. Vis B.V.","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"10","plaats":"Heenvliet","straat":"Drie\u00ebndijk 1a"}{"id":"3","title":"CijferAdvies Nissewaard","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"1","state":"1","item_id":"3","plaats":"Heenvliet","straat":"Ridderstraat 5"}{"id":"4","title":"\u201cHet Huidhuys\u201d Afslank- en schoonheidsinstituut","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"4","plaats":"Zuidland","straat":"Breedstraat 2"}{"id":"5","title":"Bouwbedrijf van de Water","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"5","plaats":"Heevliet","straat":"Polyanderweg 2"}{"id":"6","title":"Studio NewMedia B.V.","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"6","plaats":"Spijkenisse","straat":"Goudenregenplein 1 - Unit 38"}{"id":"7","title":"Taxi Overgaauw","introtext":"<p><a href=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\"><\/a><a href=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/a><\/p>\r\n<p><a href=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/a><\/p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"7","plaats":"Zuidland","straat":"Langeweg 2b"}{"id":"8","title":"Moree","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"8","plaats":"Simonshaven","straat":"Ring 2"}{"id":"9","title":"Molengraaf Makelaardij","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"9","plaats":"Zuidland","straat":"Mr. P.J. Oudweg 56"};
```

Comment: Never create string representations of objects or json yourself. Create the actual object and if you want to see it as string use `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bedrijven` variable is incorrect, there must be `,` between `{}` objects and the whole thing should be surrounded by. `[]`.

Also, you need to concatenate properly at this line:

```
address : '"+ value.straat + value.plaats +"',
```

And your code is using multiline string while `"` doesnt support multiline strings. Try the following:

```
  var bedrijvenlijst = `{
    title : '${value.title}',
      image : 'bbvdw.jpg',
      address : '${value.straat} ${value.plaats}',
      position : {
          lat : 51.863010, // 51.8424513,
          lng : 4.235398 // 4.3307054
      },
      markerIcon : 'marker-green.png'
  },`;
```

**Edit:** Or you can try a better method:

```
var bedrijvenlijst = [];
      $.each( bedrijven, function( key, value ) {
      bedrijvenlijst.push({
        title : value.title,
          image : 'bbvdw.jpg',
          address : value.straat + value.plaats,
          position : {
              lat : 51.863010, // 51.8424513,
              lng : 4.235398 // 4.3307054
          },
          markerIcon : 'marker-green.png'
      });
});
bedrijvenlijst = JSON.stringify(bedrijvenlijst);
```

This will, create a proper `json` string.

Comment: Thank you this looks a lot cleaner, but I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: bedrijvenlijst is not defined` maybe something with document.ready?

Comment: Yes, for that write `var bedrijvenlijst;` before the loop and inside the loop try `bedrijvenlijst += `{` without `var`.

Comment: @mega6382 that will overwrite the value of the variable every iteration

Comment: @charlietfl Fixed it.

Comment: @mega6382 Thanks!! I got it how I need now.

Comment: This whole string concept is all wrong and goes against sensible best practices

Comment: @mega6382 Great, how can I return the content of `bedrijvenlijst` further in my script?

Comment: @twan What do you mean?

Comment: @mega6382 I have a old var that contains the output that I am now looping, but hardcoded like a string. So how can I "echo" the output of that loop in its place?

Comment: You have to `echo` it  through dom manipulation like `document.writeln(bedrijvenlijst );`

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to build the json string than combining quotes. Instead just create the literal object. Next, store its string value in a seperate variable using `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
var bedrijvenlijst = {
  title: {}, //value.title
  image: 'bbvdw.jpg',
  address: {}, //value.straat value.plaats
  position: {
    lat: 51.863010, // 51.8424513,
    lng: 4.235398 // 4.3307054
  },
  markerIcon: 'marker-green.png'
};
console.log(bedrijvenlijst);

var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(bedrijvenlijst);
console.log(jsonStr);
```

Comment: But even if I remove the second value, I still get the error. And the error points to this part: `"{` right after when I name the variable and the equals sign.